What is the purpose of the "if" in Kofu's card text?
Kofu (Stellar Crown) has the following card text:

Put 2 cards from your hand on the bottom of your deck in any order. If you put 2 cards on the bottom of your deck in this way, draw 4 cards. (If you can't put 2 cards from your hand on the bottom of your deck, you can't use this card.)

Other than the implied unresolvable action rule being explicitly stated on the card, I found it interesting that the card specified "if" for the draw cards condition, rather than stating directly to draw four cards.
If the card text simply read:

Put 2 cards from your hand on the bottom of your deck in any order. Draw 4 cards.

Would there be any difference? Does the card's text imply that I can play the card and fail it by choosing not to pay its cost despite being able to?

There is a principle not well documented that is called ‘do as much as you can.’  That allows you to do things like play Professor’s Research and draw five with a deck of five cards.  In general, if not otherwise restricted, fulfilling as much as possible will allow you to play a card. However, that does not mean you can choose not to do things that you otherwise are known to be able to do; see this ruling:

Whether a card's effect is optional or not is determined from the card text. If there is no explicit indication that you have a choice, then you don't have one and the effect is mandatory.

In the example given, there are two separate card effects.  The ‘put two cards on the bottom’ effect and the ‘draw four cards’ effect. Both must be done if possible - as per the ruling above, nothing indicates either is optional.  Neither is related to the other in this new card text though - if you have zero cards in hand you just draw four. But if you have any cards in hand, you must put them (up to two) on the bottom of the deck.
Of course in the real card text, there is a relationship - you are required to put two exactly on the bottom to play it, similar to Ultra Ball requiring you to discard two cards to play it.

Ah ok, so the "if you put 2 cards on bottom" is there to establish the relationship that makes the cost of 2 cards mandatory?

That makes it a cost (so you can’t play the card without doing that).

It seems to me that the if alone is insufficient to make the card unplayable in the case where you have only one other card in hand. You could play Kofu, put one card on the bottom of your deck ("do as much as you can"), and then, since you did not put two cards on the bottom of your deck, not draw four cards, and end with an empty hand. The parenthetical note at the end is required to forbid this usage.

Parenthetical text is never intended that way though - it's always reminder text only.  The card would work the same way with or without it.  Most likely this is a translation-related reason; ultimately, though, the way it's implemented the "put two cards on bottom" is being considered a cost, not an effect.  It could be an effect, and often would be, but since the "if you do this" is there for whatever reason the game designers decided this is a cost, not an effect.

Ultimately in Pokémon, the game designers have a way they intend a card to be used, and you can't always intuit that way from plain English reading of the card.  Sometimes it's because of losing things to translation, sometimes it's not even that.
